# Need to arrange the words in a text file in alphabetical order

Tags: java

I have a text file full of words that I need to arrange into alphabetical order.  What are the steps I should take to do this.  I know I need to use an array but then put them in order and print it but I'm not sure of the exact details.  Also I dont know how to read each individual string becuase I only know .nextLine which takes all the strings in a line.

Been working on this for a while and not making much progress any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also dont know how to use bufferedreader which I see alot of people using my class has only been taught the scanner class so far and I don't want to go ahead.

Comment: Outline your current logic for us here,... not your code, but the logical steps that you think your program should make in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Adding the contents into an array would be difficult as (I assume) you don't know how many elements might exist.  Something like `ArrayList` might be a better solution.  You could then use `Collections.sort` to sort the list...

Comment: Yes arraylist could work.  There will be lots of elements since its for the book war and peace haha!

Comment: So my current logic would be: 1. Get the doc name as an arg from the user.  2. Make arg [0] a variable 3. Make that variable into a file and scanner class  4.Somehow scan each string out and add it to an arraylist  5.Rearrange the arraylist alpabetically 6.Printout the new arraylist.

Comment: War and Peace? WIth that many words, you might want to learn Hadoop too. (Big data cloud scale jokes are always funny.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a "global" list (not an array since you don't know the length) to hold the words and then read each line. Split each line into an array of words and then add them to this global list. Then sort this list.

Here is an example of a basic implementation of this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
ArrayList<String> allWords = new ArrayList();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = scanner.nextLine();
   String[] words = line.split(" ");
   List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words)
   allWords.addAll(wordList);             
}
scanner.close();
Collections.sort(allWords);
```

Note that I wrote this freehand so there may be syntax or even logic errors. Hopefully it gives you the basic road ahead though. Also, I didn't handle exceptions.

Hope this helps. Please ask more questions, and good luck with your Java learning!

Comment: I dont get the last 2 lines of the while loop

Comment: That first of the last two lines converts your `array` to `List` so that you can later use the `sort()` method.

Comment: Those lines aren't actually essential to the problem but rather catering to the API's I chose. So when the line is split into words by space, you get an array of Strings. This array needs to be converted into a List to then be added to the "global" list. Arrays.asList does that. Finally, the last line of the loop adds this sentence-level list to the document-level list. The addAll() method only takes a Collection as shown here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html